# iOS: How can one use custom fonts in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@font-face is deprecated on the iPhone version of Safari. What are my alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149417/font-face-is-deprecated-on-the-iphone-version-of-safari-what-are-my-alternativ)

How can one use custom fonts via `@font-face` in a `UIWebView`?

I know that it's possible to use `CGFonts` to render custom fonts on the iOS, but in my specific case I need the font to render inside a `HTML` document within a `UIWebView`.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here: [@font-face is deprecated on the iPhone version of Safari. What are my alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149417/font-face-is-deprecated-on-the-iphone-version-of-safari-what-are-my-alternative)