# iOS custom font path for UIWebViews

Tags: ios, fonts, uiwebview, path, custom-font

I have a UIWebView and I have a custom font I want to load into an editable html document that I will be displaying through the UIWebView. In my SupportingFiles (resources) folder I have "Nosifer-Regular.ttf"... To use the custom font in my HTML I need the path (URL) to the font tile... I tried doing this, but it didn't seem to work... any ideas?

```
bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    pathFont = [bundle bundlePath];
    fontURL = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"Nosifer-Regular" ofType:@"ttf" inDirectory:pathFont];
    path_font = [fontURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    fileAppend = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://"];
    path_font = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", fileAppend, path_font];
```

The HTML (CSS):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nosifer';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Nosifer'), local('Nosifer-Regular'), url('%@') format('truetype');
}
```

Where %@ is replaced with "path_font" (defined above in the first code block)

Comment: This looks like a great answer, but I can't seem to get it working - no matter what I do, my custom font (embedded as a resource) is not used. Could you post a working code sample that shows a working version of this? The extended comments in the accepted answer seem to contain the solution (like using " instead of ', but I'm not sure where).

Comment: Are you loading your content from your app bundle? Make sure the `baseURL` parameter you pass when you create your URL points to your app's resources folder.

Comment: @nielsbot Thanks! The only problem was that in a UIWebView in iOS CSS required double quotes around a font type, single quotes do not work... this has nothing to do with CSS (in _REAL_ CSS either one will work) but the way Apple programmed the UIWebViews for some reason it doesn't work... I switched my single quotes to double quotes and the code in the accepted answer (below) worked fine.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw, hy, I'm trying to do almost the same, but had no luck, do you think you can take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444788/ebooks-reader-not-capturing-embedded-font-for-epub-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, add filed "Fonts provided by application" in your `info.plist`. It will be an array like

```
item0 myFont.otf
item1 anotherFont.ttf
```

or something.

In HTML use font-face to add a font. And place your font files in the same directory with html file. If HTML is generated dynamically and not shown from bundle then you should copy font .

Good luck.

Comment: I was using font-face but what do I put for the URL? I tried just typing myFont.otf (in my case "Nosifer-Regular.ttf") and it didn't load a font it just ran the default font. So then I tried retrieving the URL to the font file with the code above. I added the fonts provided to the info plist and tried both again and still no luck /:

Comment: Do you copy your fonts from bundle to the same directory with the HTML?

Comment: I'm saving my HTML in this directory  

docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

And I NSLOGGED the location of the font files and they are here:

file:///var/mobile/Applications/************/****.app/AlmonteSnow.ttf

Comment: So I guess I need to place the font files in the same place as docsDir, how can I do that manually?

Comment: `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:src toPath:dst error:&error;`

Comment: And where you have src I would put "path_font"? This thing: "file:///var/mobile/Applications/************/****.app/AlmonteSnow.ttf"  Now what is "dst? would I put docsDir?

Comment: 'src' is source, yes, it's path to your bundle resources. And 'dst' is destination, docsDir in your example.

Comment: Hmmm /: I tried this, it isn't seeming to work: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:path_font toPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Nosifer-Regular.ttf"] error:nil];
    path_font = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Nosifer-Regular.ttf"];

Comment: Also tried this: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:path_font toPath:docsDir error:nil];
    path_font = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"AlmonteSnow.ttf"];

And this: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:fontURL toPath:docsDir error:nil];
    path_font = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"AlmonteSnow.ttf"];

Comment: Okay I can't get that working but the font loads if the HTML file is in my bundle, if the HTML file is in my directories it doesn't load (even if the font file is in my directories)... So I need to copy my HTML file to my bundle from my directories then load it, that should work I'll try it tmrw! (2:30 am here!) Thanks for all the help so far I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: "So I need to copy my HTML file to my bundle from my directories then load it" - you can't do it.
`path_font = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"AlmonteSnow.ttf"];` - is wrong,  should be `path_font = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AlmonteSnow.ttf"]`

Comment: This isn't working: `docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];`
    `NSString *path2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Nosifer-Regular.ttf"];`
    `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:path2 toPath:docsDir error:nil];`

Comment: Here is the HTML code I am saving then loading into a WebView: `<html><head><style type='text/css'>p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 30.0px; font: 34.0px;} @font-face { font-family: 'Nosifer'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: local('Nosifer'), local('Nosifer-Regular'), url('Nosifer-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'); }</style></head><body allowtransparency='true'><div style='word-wrap: break-word;'><p class='p1'><font style='font-family: 'Nosifer'; font-size:16px;' color='#FF0000'>Insert Text Here</font></p></div></body></html>`

Comment: AHHHH As it turns out we didn't have to do any of that copying stuff! The path I was using gave the right path and the html will read that, my problem was I was using single quotes ' for the CSS style tag (as to fit it in an NSString) and it requires double quotes " (I changed those to /" instead of ' and it worked fine!)

Comment: ^ in that code you don't need any of the margin, or body styles I added. that was so it would fit in my app, it may make it look weird in your app! haha! Thanks for helping me anyways! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I got a working html code example here.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 30.0px; font: 34.0px;}
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Nosifer'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: local('Nosifer'), local('Nosifer-Regular'), url('Nosifer-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
        }

        .nosifer {
            font-family: Nosifer;
        }

        </style>
</head>
<body allowtransparency='true'>
    <p class="nosifer">Nosifer ABCabc</p>
</body>
```

As you can see I used a css class to define the font more easily. I'm not sure what all that CSS code within font-face means, but it seems to work.

I confirmed that you NEED to add "Nosifer-Regular.ttf" to the array of fonts provided by the application in the ***-info.plist file (key: Fonts provided by application).
Btw I googled Nosifer-Regular.ttf and found it on a noisy site here. It really worked though: http://www.ffonts.net/Nosifer.font.download

Then, I was also able to load an OTF that I'll be using in my case. In the CSS I changed format from truetype to opentype.

Comment: That should work fine in HTML... the problem here was that I was trying to run it within my own UIWebView on iOS so the "url" section in the CSS has to use double quotes not single quotes so I replaced url('....') with url(\"...\") Again this only happens on iOS... your code will work fine for just a normal website browsing.

Comment: I used this code in iOS. Just put it in a html file, add the file to the bundle, then load the file into a NSString... something like [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile ...
It worked, although for my needs I found out a better way to use this with UILabel.
Generally though text handling on iOS really is weak :-(

Comment: Hmm, what version were you using? For whatever reason it would just NOT work for me when I originally posted this question! hmmm :) Haha

Answer (score 1):

Add your custom font in your project. Then

Get font name

```
 UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Your-Custom-font" size:20];
```

Then create html string

```
NSString *htmlHeader=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file://localhost%@\"></head><body><font face=\"%@\"; size=\"4\">HI</font></body></html>",cssPath,font.familyName];
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you'd add the font to your Info.plist:

```
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Nosifer-Regular.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

Then use @font-face as per [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5732427/516581).